# Why is a list of strings shown as an example for a "hashable object"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, set

I am currently learning Python on codecademy and I came across this statement that says that lists are hashable (thus, they can be used as input for the update method when wanting to add multiple elements to a list):

> The `.update()` method can add multiple elements.
>
> ```
> # Create a set to hold the song tags
> song_tags = {'country', 'folk', 'acoustic'}
>
> # Add more tags using a hashable object (such as a list of elements)
> other_tags = ['live', 'blues', 'acoustic']
> song_tags.update(other_tags)
>
> print(song_tags)
> ```

But searching what a hashable object was, I found out that lists are not hashable, so now I am confused. Is this a mistake or are lists hashable in this particular situation?

Answer (score 2):

Lists aren't hashable:

```
>>> hash([])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
>>> {["hello", "world"]}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

So yes, Codeacademy is incorrect here. `set.update` accepts any iterable as an argument:

```
>>> d = set(); d.update("hello"); d # string
{'h', 'l', 'o', 'e'}
>>> d = set(); d.update(['h', 'i']); d # list
{'h', 'i'}
>>> d = set(); d.update((h for h in "hello")); d # generator
{'h', 'l', 'o', 'e'}
```

The only thing that matters is that its *elements* be hashable, not the iterable itself.

Comment: This clears things up. Thank you.